# Form_for inside another Form_for rendering fields but not <form></form> Tags arroun

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Im making a custom editor for my Rails site, and I need image uploading directly into my editor with AJAX. I have everything down, the only issue is that in the image_fields, which is inside fields_for for sections which is inside a form_for for project is not wrapped in  tags. And without those form tags my AJAX/Javascript does not work

## Here's my code:

Form for project:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <h1>New Project</h1>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :involvment, "Involvement" %>
    <%= f.text_field :involvment %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :project_link, "Project Link" %>
    <%= f.text_field :project_link %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :background, class: 'btn' do %>
    Upload Image <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true" style='margin-left: 20px'></i>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.attachment_field :background, direct: true, class: "hidden" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :sections do |section| %>
  <%= render "section_fields", f: section %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Section', f, :sections, class:"clickTarget" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Fields for section / section_fields

```
<div class="nested-fields">
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <div class="editor">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <div class="toolbarItem boldText">
                <div class="button bold">
                    <i class="fa fa-bold" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toolbarItem italicText">
                <div class="button italic">
                    <i class="fa fa-italic" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toolbarItem underlineText">
                <div class="button underline">
                    <i class="fa fa-underline" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toolbarItem link">
                <div class="button able-active link">
                    <i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="toolbarSettings link">
                    <label for="linkBox">Insert link URL</label>
                    <input type="text" class="linkBox"/>
                    <button class="finEditor">Insert Link</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toolbarItem image">
                <div class="button able-active image">
                    <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="toolbarSettings link">
                    <%= render 'image_fields' %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%= f.text_area :content, class:"editorTextarea" %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Section", f, class:"clickTarget" %>
</div>
```

Form for Image/ Image_fields

```
<%= form_for @image, url: new_image_path, method: :post do |image| %>
  <%= image.label :image, "Upload an Image" %>
  <%= image.attachment_field :image, direct: true %>
  <p>Or</p>
  <%= image.label :remote_image_url, "Insert Image URL" %>
  <%= image.text_field :remote_image_url, id: "linkBox" %>
  <button class="finEditor">Insert Image</button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Form elements cannot be nested.